# Correct method to defining class for external node module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm currently writing typings for the Javascript based [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) module so it can be used in a Typescript project and play nice with the compiler.

The following currently passes `tsc` type checking, however TSlint complains that `Interfaces cannot be constructed. Did you mean declare class?`. Switching `SpotifyInstance` from `interface` to `class` however results in not being able to compile due to tsc TS2351 `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`.

What is the correct way to define this class and export it so it's used when importing the module elsewhere?

**spotify.d.ts**

```
declare module "spotify-web-api-node" {
  let instance: Spotify.SpotifyInstance;
  export = instance;
}

declare namespace Spotify {
  export interface Authorization {
    body: {
      access_token: string;
      refresh_token: string;
    };
  }

  export interface CurrentSong {
    body: {
      item: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        artists: [{
          name: string;
        }]
        album: {
          name: string;
          images: [{
            url: string
          }]
        }
      }
    };
  }

  export interface Config {
    clientId: string;
    clientSecret: string;
    redirectUri: string;
  }

  export interface SpotifyInstance {
    new(config: Config): SpotifyInstance;
    createAuthorizeURL(permissions: string[], state: string): string;
    authorizationCodeGrant(state: string): Promise<Authorization>;
    getMyCurrentlyPlaying(): Promise<CurrentSong>;
    setAccessToken(token: string): void;
    setRefreshToken(token: string): void;
  }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import * as Spotify from "spotify-web-api-node";

const spotify = new Spotify({
  clientId: "",
  clientSecret: "",
  redirectUri: ""
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont see in your code where the classes are. Interfaces do not generate any code in js after be compiled by Typescript. if you using a class then you should create a constructor to it.

```
    export class YourClassName{

       constructor() {
          // Constructor Code
       }
   }
```

Then you can do:

```
var myClass = new YourClassName();
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: `SpotifyInstance` at the botton of my typings in the first code is what I'm currently using to define the class that the external module (spotify-web-api-node). This is incorrect as interfaces can't be used to define classes, however what I'm looking to know is the correct syntax in order to define a class from an external module in my typings file.

Comment: Ahh you original code is in java-script, and you are constructing the .d file.

Comment: Yeah you got it! I made sure to add a link to the external module I'm attempting to write typings for so that I can use the module while playing nice with the Typescript compiler.